# Beam waist size inside a hemispherical cavity

Tags: optics, laser-cavity

I would like to know if the beam waist inside a laser cavity depends on the pump beam size. For example, for a hemispherical cavity with a plane pump mirror adjacent to the laser crystal, and a plano concave output coupler, will the beam waist on the plane mirror be different if I use lenses which focus the pump beam to different sizes in the crystal?